# esxi 5.5.0 - what can make trusted keys file read-only?

Tags: ssh, vmware-esxi

I have an esxi host where I want to login via ssh.

Unlike at the other esxi host I have, I can't edit `/etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys` there: even though it has mode 644, it is not writable.

I believe there's an option somewhere in advanced settings to fix this, but I can't find it.

Search returns video guides on how to edit the file with vi or nano, which is neat but sort of not too helpful.

Answer (score 0):

OK, whatever caused it, this is a way to fix it: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/332790 (backup, remove and recreate)